# Static quantization on efficientNet

Tags: python

I've tried to perform static quantization with a trained EfficientNetB0. Once I apply the torch.quantization.convert to transform the model from float32 to int8, an error occurs, specifically: NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::silu.out' with arguments from the 'QuantizedCPU' backend. I wonder if anyone has run into the same error and been able to resolve it. I have also tried with mobilenet and I get an error of the style (not the same).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi @alex, welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silu, Leaky ReLu is not easy to be implemented in 8bit quantization and a lot of frameworks are not able to implement it without model degradation (256 numbers represent for the whole output range).

However, there is a trick to quantize this layer in 8-bit

1/ You can try to inference the training dataset and measure the output activation range of this layer to replicate the boundary from this function. This is usually called PostQuantize

2/ Reduce the complexity of the activation function. SiLu `x*sigmoid(x)` => HardSwish `x*relu6(x + 3)*0.166666667`. This is the idea of ReLu => ReLu6 where the output is bounded from 0-6.